# Why Chrome Dev tools (network tab) doesn't show the response for a request? (Failed to load response data: No resource with given identifier found))

Tags: rest, google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I have been unable to deduce why Chrome(97.x.x.x) is unable to load the response for a successful POST XHR. It displays the following message in the response section:
`Failed to load response data: No resource with given identifier found`

However, I could see the response for the same in the Firefox(96.x.x).

PS: I can see the headers, payload and other section properly.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had an issue with too many re-renders and encountered this behavior. The GET request worked fine, but a bug in my code caused too many re renderings and I am not sure why (perhaps because I use react-query, perhaps because of that bug I had) there was a new attempt to get the data when the application was in an error state. That ended in a response exactly like the one you describe, same message and all.

Comment: But the same requests will show proper response in Firefox for example I have lately encountered this behaviour a lot. I believe there are strict protocols/security policies which are respected by chrome and firefox is a bit relaxed on them

Answer (score 0):

untick the "Preserve log" option and load the page again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it's working but can you provide more information why

Comment: This suggestion actually fixed the "Failed to load response data" problem, allowing me to see, (minus the HTML garbage): "Warning:  Undefined variable $lockoutSpan in ****.php on line 161....", allowing me to find and fix my issue, as I had simply neglected to declare a global inside a function.  So, thanks user16886990, if you're still out there.  For the record, I am using XAMPP.   One downvote cancelled by my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the issue was with the backend server configurations. Setting the environment variable as Development resolved the issue.

I hope it helps at least with figuring out some things.